# How can I modify/overwrite a pointcloud ply file with python?

Tags: python, android, overwrite, point-cloud-library, ply-file-format

I have read the lon dress pointcloud.ply file and I converted theRGB channel into ycbcr so from x,y,z,r,g,b 6channelt to  x,y,z,ycbcr 4 channel. But I couldn't find how to overwrite the original ply flw with the changes I made.

Comment: The basic workflow is as follows:

1. Use plyfile.PlyData.read() to read the ply file into a PlyData object.
2. Manipulate the PlyData object by modifying the data array and other attributes.
3. Use plyfile.PlyData.write() to write the modified PlyData object back to the ply file.

Comment: Thank you, I could see the workflow but I just don't know how to implement the idea. I dont know where and  how to implement PlyData.write(); overall, I created the new dataframe I mentioned from my question post and now I need to swtich it with the original part